# Alignment of TikZ pictures in enumerate environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, enumerate

I want to draw some trees in `tikz` and align them like this (mockup):

[image: mockup]

Note that the enumerations align to the top.

Ideally, this should "just work", breaking lines as needed, and automatically sizing the width of all these graphics.

My best take so far is this:

[image: screenshot]

The numbers don't line up, and I could not convince them to do so with the `[t]` argument. Also, I had to specify each width manually:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\newenvironment{tikztree}
{
    \tikzpicture[sibling distance=1cm, level distance=1cm, baseline]
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[draw, circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2mm]
}{
    \endtikzpicture
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \begin{minipage}{2cm}\item \begin{tikztree}[baseline]\Tree[.{} ];\end{tikztree}\end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{2cm}\item \begin{tikztree}[baseline]\Tree[.{} [.{} ] ];\end{tikztree}\end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{3cm}\item \begin{tikztree}[baseline]\Tree[.{} [.{} ] [.{} ] ];\end{tikztree}\end{minipage}
        \vspace{5ex}

        \begin{minipage}{4cm}\item \begin{tikztree}[baseline]\Tree[.{} [.{} [.{} ] [.{} ] ] [.{} ] ];\end{tikztree}\end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{2cm}\item \begin{tikztree}[baseline]\Tree[.{} [.{} [.{} ] ] ];\end{tikztree}\end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{3cm}\item \begin{tikztree}[baseline]\Tree[.{} [.{} [.{} ] [.{} ] ] ];\end{tikztree}\end{minipage}
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

What's the best way to accomplish that?

Comment: Why not have everything in the `tikzpicture`? That would be easier. Or would you rather not have that?

Comment: I simply don't know how to get automatic line-breaking and enumeration in `tikz`.

Comment: Why do you need the option `[baseline]` for the `tikztree` environment? Also, `\tikzstyle` is considered obsolete, `\tikzset` in recommended. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles

Comment: Baseline sets the baseline to the top, so that the `\item` ends up on top. Thanks for the `\tikzstyle` hint!

Comment: Oops, you meant *that* baseline. I forgot the remove that while building the MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same approach with `minipage`s. Give same (suitable) width to all `minipage`s and use `\hfill`s.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\newenvironment{tikztree}
{
    \tikzpicture[sibling distance=1cm, level distance=1cm, baseline]
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[draw, circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2mm]
}{
    \endtikzpicture
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}\item \begin{tikztree}[baseline]\Tree[.{} ];\end{tikztree}\end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}\item \begin{tikztree}[baseline]\Tree[.{} [.{} ] ];\end{tikztree}\end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}\item \begin{tikztree}[baseline]\Tree[.{} [.{} ] [.{} ] ];\end{tikztree}\end{minipage}
        \vspace{5ex}

        \begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}\item \begin{tikztree}[baseline]\Tree[.{} [.{} [.{} ] [.{} ] ] [.{} ] ];\end{tikztree}\end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}\item \begin{tikztree}[baseline]\Tree[.{} [.{} [.{} ] ] ];\end{tikztree}\end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}\item \begin{tikztree}[baseline]\Tree[.{} [.{} [.{} ] [.{} ] ] ];\end{tikztree}\end{minipage}
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Response to the comments:

We need `[t]` specifier so as to make all trees aligned at the top without them the trees will be aligned at the center (vertically). Further, `\hfill` will ensure that the `item`s are equally distributed horizontally and hence are aligned.

Comment: I accepted your answer, since it seems to be the simplest fix, without further dependencies. Is there an easy explanation why you need *both* `[t]` and `\hfill`?

Comment: @fefrei Thanks and I added some clarifications. Feel free if anything is needed more. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick solution using the `multienumerate` package. It is not the most robust package but does the trick. Wait for other solutions and compare.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\newenvironment{tikztree}
{
    \tikzpicture[sibling distance=1cm, level distance=1cm, baseline]
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[draw, circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2mm]
}{
    \endtikzpicture
}
\usepackage{multienum}

\begin{document}

\begin{multienumerate}
    \mitemxxx{%
        \begin{tikztree}[baseline]
        \Tree[.{} ];
        \end{tikztree}
        }{%
        \begin{tikztree}[baseline]
        \Tree[.{} [.{} ] ];
        \end{tikztree}
        }{%
        \begin{tikztree}[baseline]
        \Tree[.{} [.{} ] [.{} ] ];
        \end{tikztree}
        }
    \vskip\baselineskip
    \mitemxxx{%
        \begin{tikztree}[baseline]
        \Tree[.{} [.{} [.{} ] [.{} ] ] [.{} ] ];
        \end{tikztree}
        }{%
        \begin{tikztree}[baseline]
        \Tree[.{} [.{} [.{} ] ] ];
        \end{tikztree}
        }{%
        \begin{tikztree}[baseline]
        \Tree[.{} [.{} [.{} ] [.{} ] ] ];
        \end{tikztree}
        }
\end{multienumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The inline lists offered by `enumitem` package is also a possibility.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\newenvironment{tikztree}
{
    \tikzpicture[sibling distance=1cm, level distance=1cm, baseline]
    \tikzset{every node/.style={draw, circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2mm}}
}{
    \endtikzpicture
}

\begin{document}
All in one line with automatic line break:

\noindent
\begin{enumerate*}[itemjoin=\hfill]
\item \begin{tikztree}\Tree[.{} ];\end{tikztree}
\item \begin{tikztree}\Tree[.{} [.{} ] ];\end{tikztree}
\item \begin{tikztree}\Tree[.{} [.{} ] [.{} ] ];\end{tikztree}
\item \begin{tikztree}\Tree[.{} [.{} [.{} ] [.{} ] ] [.{} ] ];\end{tikztree}
\item \begin{tikztree}\Tree[.{} [.{} [.{} ] ] ];\end{tikztree}
\item \begin{tikztree}\Tree[.{} [.{} [.{} ] [.{} ] ] ];\end{tikztree}
\item \begin{tikztree}\Tree[.{} ];\end{tikztree}
\item \begin{tikztree}\Tree[.{} [.{} ] ];\end{tikztree}
\item \begin{tikztree}\Tree[.{} [.{} ] [.{} ] ];\end{tikztree}
\item \begin{tikztree}\Tree[.{} [.{} [.{} ] [.{} ] ] [.{} ] ];\end{tikztree}
\item \begin{tikztree}\Tree[.{} [.{} [.{} ] ] ];\end{tikztree}
\item \begin{tikztree}\Tree[.{} [.{} [.{} ] [.{} ] ] ];\end{tikztree}
\end{enumerate*}

\vskip30pt
Break into two lines:

\noindent
\begin{enumerate*}[itemjoin=\hfill]
\item \begin{tikztree}\Tree[.{} ];\end{tikztree}
\item \begin{tikztree}\Tree[.{} [.{} ] ];\end{tikztree}
\item \begin{tikztree}\Tree[.{} [.{} ] [.{} ] ];\end{tikztree}
\end{enumerate*}
\\ \bigskip
\begin{enumerate*}[itemjoin=\hfill,resume]
\item \begin{tikztree}\Tree[.{} [.{} [.{} ] [.{} ] ] [.{} ] ];\end{tikztree}
\item \begin{tikztree}\Tree[.{} [.{} [.{} ] ] ];\end{tikztree}
\item \begin{tikztree}\Tree[.{} [.{} [.{} ] [.{} ] ] ];\end{tikztree}
\end{enumerate*}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `tasks` package (which is part of the `exsheets` package) is what I use in similar situations.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tasks}

\newenvironment{tikztree}
{
\tikzpicture[sibling distance=1cm, level distance=1cm, baseline]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw, circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2mm]
}{
\endtikzpicture
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}[after-item-skip = 5ex, counter-format = tsk. ](3)
    \task \begin{tikztree}\Tree[.{} ];\end{tikztree}
    \task \begin{tikztree}\Tree[.{} [.{} ] ];\end{tikztree}
    \task \begin{tikztree}\Tree[.{} [.{} ] [.{} ] ];\end{tikztree}
    \task \begin{tikztree}\Tree[.{} [.{} [.{} ] [.{} ] ] [.{} ] ];\end{tikztree}
    \task \begin{tikztree}\Tree[.{} [.{} [.{} ] ] ];\end{tikztree}
    \task \begin{tikztree}\Tree[.{} [.{} [.{} ] [.{} ] ] ];\end{tikztree}
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image: trees in tasks enviroment]

(Also, since you put `baseline` in your environment definition, you don't need it for each tree.)